# Joining POSIX threads returns 3

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

So here is my code concerning threads. My problem is that I create a thread with a JOINABLE attribute (I know it is the default value) yet when I reach the call to `pthread_join()`, the return value is equal to `3` instead of `0`. I dont understand why...

```
void* blue(struct image *img)
{
    printf("Launching blue filter\n");
    if (filter_blue(img))
    {
    perror("Error calling filter_blue");
    pthread_exit((void*)1);
}
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

// in main file:
pthread_t thread[parameters.num_threads];
pthread_attr_t attr;
pthread_attr_init(&attr);
pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&attr, PTHREAD_CREATE_JOINABLE);
for (j=parameters->num_threads - parameters->num_threads_left; count < img->blue_threads ; j++)
{
    pthread_create(&thread[j], &attr, (void*)blue, img);
    printf("blue found\n");
    count++;
}

void *status;
for (i=0; i<num_thread; i++)
{
    int a = pthread_join(thread[i], &status);
    printf("pthread join return value: %d \n",a);
}
pthread_attr_destroy(&attr);
```

Comment: Your code doesn't show where `num_thread` is declared, or how `num_thread` receives the correct value reflecting the number of threads in the array. For that matter, it's not obvious that the thread creation loop even starts placing the threads at `thread[0]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `pthread_*` family of functions returns values as found in  `errno`.

`3` is `ESRCH`, which ([at least under Linux](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_join.3.html)) indicates that a value for `thread` (1<sup>st</sup> parameter to `pthread_join()`) was passed that does not match an existing thread.

As the code you show is not clear about which indicies are used to store the `pthread_t` value returned by the calls to `pthread_create()` it is not possible to provide anymore specific hints for fixing this, but just proposing to **double** check how the elements of the array `thread` are accessed. Using a debugger might help significantly to do so.